# Why are two strings or two arrays necessary to accomplish this?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

This method is essentially taking an array that contains percentages, and based on whether or not the percentages are above or below 50%, a letter is appended onto a returned String to result in a final type.

I was told that I should "should create either two Strings or two arrays
that hold the characters, then loop through the dimensions and
test percentageB[i] with the 3 tests"

I don't understand why doing this is necessarily more valid or effective than the method I have already used. Could someone explain this to me?

```
public static String getPersonality(int[] percentageB) {
    char [] types = {'E','I','S','N','T','F','J','P'};
    String MBTItype = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j += 2) {
        int i = j/2;
        if (percentageB[i] < 50){
            MBTItype += types[j];
        } else if (percentageB[i] > 50) {
            MBTItype += types[j + 1];
        } else if (percentageB[i] == 50) {
            MBTItype += 'X';
        }
    }
    return MBTItype;
}
```

Comment: It is easier to count through `{'E', 'S', 'T', 'J'}` and take the matching one from `{'I', 'N', 'F', 'P'}`, especially since your `percentages` also has four elements, rather than do all the arithmetic. But it is not really all that big of a deal.

Comment: The only reason to work with 2 type arrays is code understandability and readability. Just for fun read this piece from Linus http://www.itworld.com/article/2999968/linux/linus-torvalds-rants-against-bad-code.html and then look at your code again and pretend you are a different person: How understandable is it? Is it necessary to make it more complex (like what you did)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you would have been told to use two arrays is that it makes the relationship between the letters clearer, at each position you are assigned the letter from one of the two lists. By combining them into a single array you are not making the mutually exclusive nature of the letters obvious to a reader of your code. Compare this implementation with your own

```
public static String getPersonality(int[] percentageB) {
    char [] lowPercentTypes =  {'E','S','T','J'};
    char [] highPercentTypes = {'I','N','F','P'};
    String MBTItype = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < lowPercentTypes.length; i++) {
        if (percentageB[i] < 50){
            MBTItype += lowPercentTypes[i];
        } else if (percentageB[i] > 50) {
            MBTItype += highPercentTypes[i];
        } else if (percentageB[i] == 50) {
            MBTItype += 'X';
        }
    }
    return MBTItype;
}
```

Reading this you do not need to go through the mental effort of knowing that each type has its compliment in the next item of the array, instead you are explicitly told that it is a high/low percentage type.

We are trying to reduce the cognitive load on the future reader of your code so you want to make things as straightforward as possible